# How can I fill the region between 2 lines in OpenCV c++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this image with 2 curves:
[image]

How could I fill the region between the red and blue curve?

Comment: you need those lines as lists of points. if you don't have that already, findNonZero is useful, but check to make sure the order of points is sensible. you could apply a convex hull. if your lines aren't straight, the convex hull (over the set of points from both lines) can and will give you a goofy result. best to get each line as a properly ordered list of points, then stitch both lines together, in the right order, i.e. concatenate. that'll work better.

Comment: please provide point lists for both lines, or explain how else the lines were created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simple way and code how you can get it:

- Check each row pixel by pixel
- If you meet non-black pixel index values 2 times, then save these points
- Fill between these 2 points with the desired color

Here is the output and code:

## Output:

[image]

## Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>


int main()
{

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("/ur/img/dir/images.png");

    for(int i=0; i<img.rows; i++)
    {
        bool started = 0;
        int startX = 0, stopX = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<img.cols; j++)
        {


                if(img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(j,i))[0] != 0)
                {
                    started = 1;

                    if(startX)
                        stopX = j;

                }
                else if(started)
                {
                    if(startX == 0)
                    startX = j;

                    started = 0;
                }



        }

        if(startX && stopX)
        {
            for(int k=startX; k<stopX; k++)
            {
                img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(k,i))[0] = 0;
                img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(k,i))[1] = 255;
                img.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(k,i))[2] = 255;

            }
        }
    }

    cv::imshow("Test",img);
    cv::waitKey(0);


    return 0;
}
```